# In Git, how to create a branch after resolving conflicts?

Tags: git, merge

I frequently find myself in this situation:

- pull changes from an upstream repo (implying merge)
- the merge causes conflicts
- resolve the conflicts
- decide to commit not to the current branch but a new one

In the last step, I use `git checkout -b new-branch-name`, but after invoking that command, the current head no longer has references to the pulled changes. It only has one parent. It's no longer a merge.

How can I, while performing a merge, commit that merge to a new branch?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I avoid `git pull`.  By avoiding it, I can first run `git fetch`, then inspect what's coming in.  Having looked, I then use `git merge` but usually wind up *also* avoiding this particular mistake in the first place because I can see that the merge might be difficult and start on a new branch in advance.

Still, it *is* useful to be able to recover ... and it's easy!  Just do this, as you did already:

```
git pull
# oh no, merge conflicts!
# resolve conflicts
git commit                    # or git merge --continue
```

and commit to the *wrong* branch, and then fix it up afterward:

```
git branch new-branch-name    # create new branch to contain the merge
git reset --hard HEAD^1       # back up current branch to first-parent
git checkout new-branch-name  # return to new branch
```

Diagrammatically, you start with:

```
    o--o--o   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
   /
...
   \
    o--o--o   <-- origin/your-branch
```

The conclusion of the merge advances `your-branch` to point to the new merge commit `*` you make:

```
    o--o--o
   /       \
...         *   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
   \       /
    o--o--o   <-- origin/your-branch
```

We now add a *new* branch, pointing to this same merge commit:

```
    o--o--o
   /       \
...         *   <-- your-branch (HEAD), new-branch-name
   \       /
    o--o--o   <-- origin/your-branch
```

and then use `git reset` to drag the branch name to which `HEAD` is attached back one step, in the first-parent direction, which restores it to its previous commit:

```
    o--o--o   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
   /       \
...         *   <-- new-branch-name
   \       /
    o--o--o   <-- origin/your-branch
```

and we're all set.

All of this relies on a useful principle about Git: Git is really all about *commits*.  The branch names move around all the time; they're just how we *find* the commits.  The *commits* are permanent (well, as long as we can find them) and unchangeable.  Get the commits the way you like and then you can reshuffle the *names* at leisure.

(If `HEAD^1` is hard to type for various reasons, note that you can use any of `HEAD^` or `HEAD~` or even `@^` or `@~`.  That is:

- `HEAD` and `@` are synonyms.
- The `^1` and `^` without 1, as suffixes, are synonyms: the `1` is implied if you omit it.
- The `~1` and `~` without 1, as suffixes, are synonyms: the `1` is implied if you omit it.
- While `^` and `~` do different things, both mean "go back some number of steps in the graph".

The number after the `^` is the parent-number and is meaningful only for merge commits: `1` means *first parent*.  So `HEAD^1` means *first parent of `HEAD`*, and `HEAD~1` means *go back one first-parent*.  Applying all the synonym rules is what gives us the `@^` and `@~` constructs.)

Comment: This is helpful, and answers the question, but is useful only if you remember not to create the new branch. If you've already created the new branch, you've lost the merge ancestry. What I really _meant_ to ask is how can one recover from the situation where the merge is lost.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs You failed to commit the merge.

Comment: There's a "cheat" way to re-create the merge, but I don't really advise it since it's messing with Git internals that you shouldn't make assumptions about: run `git rev-parse old-branch@{upstream} > $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/MERGE_HEAD` after `git checkout -b new-branch-name`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-committing merge, change branch, commit there

```
git checkout <yourbranch>
git fetch
git merge --no-commit origin/<yourbranch>

# if conflicts : resolve conflicts then

git checkout -b <newbranch>

# if NO conflicts, just

git add path/to/relevant/files
git commit
```

Comment: I tried that, but at the point I run `git checkout -b new-branch`, the merge is lost, [illustrated here](https://gist.github.com/1c868c78ecf8fd8c8a9791261bacd78e).

Answer (score 1):

Answering a slightly different question - if you've already used `git checkout -b new-branch` to create the branch, your merge isn't completely lost. Here's how I recovered: First, stash the changes. Then re-run the merge using `strategy=ours`, then re-apply the stashed changes and commit.

```
git merge upstream/master
# resolve conflicts
git checkout -b new-branch
# oh, noes! merge lost.
git stash
git merge upstream/master --no-commit --strategy=ours
git stash pop
git commit
```